# Letting users sort posts

Tags: wp-query

I'd like to create a page for filtering posts based on a number of criteria.

I can work with wp_query and deliver posts quite easily, my problem is that I can't figure out (nor can i find any answers online about this, believe me I looked) how to let users do this.

Take this for example, returns the posts in order of price (custom field meta value)from highest to lowest with 33 posts.

```
<?php 

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => 33,
   'meta_key'=>'Price',  
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order' => DESC
) ); 

?>

<?php if ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<article <?php post_class('item-post block'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h2 class="price-title"><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>

</article> <!-- end div post -->

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, even after reading and googling, I'll be god damned if I can figure out how I'd implement this on the front end for users to filter posts.

I mean, I know you can append URL's in wordpress to alter the order of posts, but in this context I'm totally lost.

What I'm trying to achieve is actually quite simple as well, let the user choose the category, choose the price range (guessing I'd write something in jquery to deliver a value into an  field), set the number of results they'd like to be returned.

I've tried googling EVERYTHING under the sun I can think of for this, no dice.

Comment: The easiest way would be to make an ajax call and use the parameters to do the query and return it. That will work

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62323/adding-sorting-to-website   ,    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/drop-downsort-blog-posts-date-added-most-popular   ,   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/sort-by-custom-field-value  These links provide the way. Cheers :)

Comment: Those answers aren't really applicable to what I'm doing.